# R Error in today() : could not find function "today"

Tags: r

I have an R script that just prints todays date. It runs just fine in Rstudio but when set as a task within a batch file it produces the following error

```
Warning message:
package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.4.4 
Loading required package: NLP
Warning message:
package 'tm' was built under R version 3.4.4 
Error in today() : could not find function "today"
Execution halted
```

**Here is the script:**

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(tm)

yesterday <- today()
yesterday <- gsub("-", "", yesterday, fixed=TRUE)

print(yesterday)
```

**Batch File:**

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH --vanilla --slave "C:\Users\mike\Desktop\Make_Task\TEST_YESTERDAY.R"
timeout /t 5
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you don't know where an R function comes from, I'd recommend searching [rdocumentation.org for the name of the function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/search?q=today). In these results, you can see that `today` is from the `lubridate` package.

Personally, I would recommend removing the external dependency by using the built-in `Sys.Date()` instead. But adding `library(lubridate)` to the top of your script should also work (assuming `lubridate` is installed).

Comment: I went with Sys.Date(). Less dependancies the better. Thank you for the resource page!

Answer (score 3):

The `today()` function is from the `lubridate` package. You probably loaded the package manually inside RStudio, so it's not in your code. Just add `library(lubridate)` to the beginning of your script and it should be fine.

Alternatively, you could also use `Sys.Date()` from r-base

Answer (score 1):

Try with `lubridate` first and then try `today()` or `now()` you will get the answer.

```r
install.packages("lubridate")

library("lubridate")

today()

[1] "2021-04-26"

now()

[1] "2021-04-26 07:09:37 UTC"
```